# GDB - map address to line and column in source code

Tags: gdb, debug-information

Both gcc and clang have option `-gcolumn-info`, which is described this way:

> Emit location column information into DWARF debugging information, rather than just file and line.

I have compiled my binary with this option. Now I have address of some instruction and want to translate it back to source file, line number **and column**. Is there a way to do it in gdb? Is there some other tool that can extract this information?

I know that I can use `info line *0xabcd1234` in gdb to get the source file and line corresponding to that address, but it does not show the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my guestion, I found one way to get the information using `lldb` and `image lookup` command:

```
(lldb) image lookup --address 0x134adc
      Address: libaaa.so[0x0000000000134adc] (libaaa.so.PT_LOAD[0]..text + 1030908)
      Summary: libaaa.so`test() + 272 at test.cpp:1842:124
```